# Ajax query to fetch json data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, netflix

I am trying to fetch title from one api, but getting some error. This is my 3rd time using ajax. 
Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Here is My code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Search Movies</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #movieTemplateContainer div
        {
            width:500px;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            border: black solid 1px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<label>Search Movies:</label>
<input id="movieName" size="50" />
<button id="btnLookup">Lookup</button>

<div id="movieTemplateContainer"></div>

  <script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div>      
         <img src="${BoxArt.LargeUrl}" />
        <strong>${Name}</strong>
        </br>
        <button id="playButton" movieID=${NetflixApiId} onclick="play(this)">Play Now</button>
        <p>
        {{html Synopsis}}
        </p>
  </div>  
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#btnLookup").click(function () {

        // Build OData query
        var movieName = $("#movieName").val();
        var query = "http://netflixroulette.net/api/api.php?" // netflix base url
        + "title=" + escape(movieName) // top-level resour

        // Make JSONP call to Netflix
     $.ajax({
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: query,
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            success: callback
            });
        });

    function callback(result) {
        // unwrap result
        var movies = result.d.results;

        $("#movieTemplateContainer").empty();
        $("#movieTemplate").tmpl(movies).appendTo("#movieTemplateContainer");
    }

    </script>


<script src="http://jsapi.netflix.com/us/api/js/api.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

I am using this [API](http://netflixroulette.net/api/api.php?title=Attack%20on%20titan)

Please let me know how I can fix the error.

Comment: *"but getting some error"* ... what error? Be specific! Take some time to read through [ask]

Comment: Jsonp is not a datatype

Comment: @Vivick it certainly is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the p in data type.  JSONP is refering to JSON padding.  Also its good practice to include an error function so that you are able to see data even if it fails:

```
  $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: query,
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            success: callback,
            error: failed
        });
    });

    function callback(result) {
        console.log(result);
        // unwrap result
        var movies = result.d.results;

        $("#movieTemplateContainer").empty();
        $("#movieTemplate").tmpl(movies).appendTo("#movieTemplateContainer");
    }

    function failed(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
```

Comment: _"Drop the p in data type. JSONP is refering to JSON padding"_ And why? And an error handler with just one parameter won't tell you anything useful...

Comment: Thanks It is working, But I am not getting the data in Html. In console i am getting. Can you help me with that.

Comment: The returned object has parameters.  so in your jquery it should show data like:
result.director, result.show_cast, etc